# how to mock a func inside thefile.pl instead of a module

Tags: unit-testing, perl

In a scenario that it is nice to not to change the code, but adding tests

the code to be tested `thefile.pl`

```
get_name{
    return 'sth';
}
```

test `test_thefile.t`

```
use Test::More;
use Test::MockModule;
require thefile.pl
my $module = Test::MockModule->new('thefile.pl')
$module->mock(get_name => sub { return 'othername' });
my $name = get_name();
ok($name eq 'othername');
```

I got

```
Invalid package name thefile.pl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the filename as a bare word, so Perl interprets that as a package name. Since `.` isn't a legal identifier character (a char you can use in a package name), you get that warning.

If you want to use a filename, use a string instead:

```
require 'file.pl';
```

Then, in the call to `Test::MockModule`, it's expecting the name of a package that you defined in *file.pl* rather than the file name.

I don't know what you are doing, but when I want to replace a subroutine definition, I just override it. This is the core of the idea and there are ways to do it temporarily. The code behind the interfaces such as `Test::MockModule` and `Hook::LexWrap` aren't that complicated:

```
BEGIN {
    require 'file.pl';

    package Some::Package;
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *get_name = sub { ... }
    }
```

The glob (`*get_name`) is a bit tricky, but just about everything else already shows up in your example. I show some of these tricks in [Effective Perl Programming](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com). For my work, reducing the module dependency list (especially in tests) is often worth the advanced trick.

Comment: `replace a subroutine definition`, that is exactly what I wanted, and it works, Thanks!